# use sass styles globally in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, sass, styles

I tried to use sass globally in the vue.js app using this method :

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = {
    css:{
        loaderOptions:{
            sass:{
                data:`@import "@/sass/test.scss";`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but in vue.config.js i have these 2 lines of code:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({transpileDependencies: true})
```

I've tried to put a comma between them and it didn't work, I've also tried to remove the first two lines and it won't work, I've searched but all the results were old,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've figured it out, go to your main.js and import your main sass file (or whatever files you have) and it'll work just fine.